# My custom 404 page doesn't work (Pyramid framework)

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, pyramid

I want to show my fancy 404 page in pyramid app, but can get it working. After reading various magic texts about the subject, I put something like this in my code:

```
cfg.add_view( "Page_not_found_view", renderer="page_404.mak", 
               context=HTTPNotFound )
```

But while my *Page_not_found_view* handler is invoked (I can see its' trace) I still get that poor "default" 404 page instead of *my own page_404.mak*. Any ideas?

Comment: Should it be .mako and not .mak?

Comment: I use .mak and so does the pyramid book... i think either work fine

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example app that uses an exception view to catch the pyramid.httpexceptions.HTTPNotFound view raised by Pyramid when no view can be found that matches:

```
from waitress import serve
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response

def hello_world(request):
    return Response('<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>')

def notfound(request):
    return Response('<html><body>Not found!</body></html>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_view(hello_world)
    config.add_view(notfound, context='pyramid.httpexceptions.HTTPNotFound')
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Visiting '/' will return "Hello world!", visiting "/abc" or "/def" (or anything else that isn't found) will return "Not found!".

Comment: Yes, this works. Still the question is why didn't my code work? Your answer gives me a hint. Looks like (renderer="page_404.mak") machinery didn't work for 404 handlers. I got my code working after replace it with "manual" rendering, like: render_to_response('page_404.mak', {page-params-here},                          request=request)

Answer (score 2):

What @chris-mcdonough wrote should work in most cases.  However, if you are using a matchdict in your view callable and want to show your custom 404 page when nothing matches, make sure that you raise the `HTTPNotFound` exception instead of returning it.  Otherwise, you will get the default 404 page.

Example:

```
from pyramid import httpexceptions

def my_page(self):
    id = self.request.matchdict.get('id', None)
    if not id:
        raise httpexceptions.HTTPNotFound()
    else:
        # do whatever here
```

Comment: Thanks for the important note! Actually I have found that my code suffered from both problems. First of all - my template haven't been in effect (specifying template by "renderer" parameter doesn't work) and then I haven't raised the exception but returned it instead.